# How to find substring ignoring the data inside comment

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find substring from an HTML string by ignoring the commented code. I have tried something like below but it is nor giving me expected result , Any pointer will be really appreciated.

```
let a = `<div data-bind="attr: {id: componentId + 'MasterDetailContainer'}"
     style="height: 100%; width: 100%">

    <!-- master --> <!-- Bug 31793483 adding aria label -->
    <div role="navigation" data-bind="attr: {id: componentId + 'MasterDetailStartDrawer'}">`;
 
let databindIndex =a.indexOf('data-bind');
//Get all the data till next valid starting tag ignoring commented code
let data =a.indexOf(/<\w\s/g,databindIndex);
console.log(data);
```

Expected output

```
`data-bind="attr: {id: componentId + 'MasterDetailContainer'}"
         style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
    
        <!-- master --> <!-- Bug 31793483 adding aria label -->`
```

Comment: No, actually I am searching for element with data-bind property and get all the data for that tag till the next valid start tag ,In my case I want data from index 5 to  170

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```js
const text = `<div data-bind="attr: {id: componentId + 'MasterDetailContainer'}"
     style="height: 100%; width: 100%">

    <!-- master --> <!-- Bug 31793483 adding aria label -->
    <div role="navigation" data-bind="attr: {id: componentId + 'MasterDetailStartDrawer'}">`

const pattern = /data-bind[^\>]*>[\s\S]*<!--[\s\S]*?-->/

const result = text.match(pattern)

console.log({result})
```

Comment: It works but it not always mandatory to have a commented code between tag there could be a scenario where we don't have <!--  -->, so the regex require a modification

Comment: @Umesh try this: `/data-bind[^\>]*>([\s\S]*<!--[\s\S]*-->)?/`